# OnReceive OnReceive firing twice

Tags: android, xamarin, broadcastreceiver

I've written this Xamarin for Android code to be notified when the network connectivity of the device changes. Why is OnReceive firing twice when I enable or disable wifi or airplane mode?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Content.PM;
using Android.Net;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;

namespace BroadcastReceiverTest
{
  [BroadcastReceiver(Enabled = true, Exported = true)]
  [IntentFilter(new string[] { ConnectivityManager.ConnectivityAction })]
  public class MyBroadcastReceiver : BroadcastReceiver
  {
    private const string TAG = "MyBroadcastReceiver";

    public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
      ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager)context.GetSystemService(Context.ConnectivityService);
      NetworkInfo activeNetInfo = connectivityManager.ActiveNetworkInfo;
      if (activeNetInfo != null)
      {
        Android.Util.Log.Debug(TAG, "Receiver : " + activeNetInfo);
      }
      else
      {
        Android.Util.Log.Debug(TAG, "Receiver : " + "No network");
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Is there someone who can answer this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know if what I say is in Xamarin's documentation, but this happens because you're probably using the class attribute `BroadcastReceiver`.

In my tests, to put this attribute in the class is no longer necessary to register the Receiver class by RegisterReceiver method or the Android Manifest file of the application.

Try the following example, using the application template blank Xamarin for Android:

**BatrianoReceiver.cs**

```
//Comment this line if you register the Receiver class with RegisterReceiver method or in the Android Manifest file
[BroadcastReceiver(Label = "Batriano custom Receiver")]
[IntentFilter(new string[] { "com.batressc.batriano.CUSTOM_RECEIVER" })]
public class BatrianoReceiver : BroadcastReceiver {
    public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        string extraData = intent.GetStringExtra("BatrianoData");
        if (extraData != null) Log.Info("batriano", extraData);
        else Log.Warn("batriano", "No se encontraron datos");
    }
}
```

**MainActivity.cs**

```
[Activity(Label = "Uso Receivers", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
public class MainActivity : Activity {
    private BatrianoReceiver receiver;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle) {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
        Button button = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.MyButton);
        button.Click += (sender, e) => {
            Intent batriano = new Intent();
            batriano.SetAction("com.batressc.batriano.CUSTOM_RECEIVER");
            batriano.PutExtra("BatrianoData", string.Format("{0}-{1}", Guid.NewGuid(), DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss.fff tt")));
            SendBroadcast(batriano);
        };
        //Uncomment this line if you comment [BroadcastReceiver] attribute and register the receiver class with RegisterReceiver method of in Android Manifest file
        //Register();
    }

    protected override void OnStop() {
        base.OnStop();
        //Uncomment this line if you comment [BroadcastReceiver] attribute and register the receiver class with RegisterReceiver method of in Android Manifest file
        //Unregister();
    }

    protected override void OnResume() {
        base.OnResume();
        //Uncomment this line if you comment [BroadcastReceiver] attribute and register the receiver class with RegisterReceiver method of in Android Manifest file
        //Register();
    }

    private void Unregister() {
        if (receiver != null) {
            UnregisterReceiver(receiver);
            receiver = null;
        }
    }

    private void Register() {
        if (receiver == null) {
            receiver = new BatrianoReceiver();
            RegisterReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter("com.batressc.batriano.CUSTOM_RECEIVER"));
        }
    }
}
```